# Convert part of line of RDD in Spark Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, split, int, rdd

I have a RDD in Spark with records like this:

```
1::F::1::10::48067
2::M::56::16::70072
3::M::25::15::55117
```

I need to convert "M" to 1 and "F" to 0 in all records for result like this:

```
1::0::1::10::48067
2::1::56::16::70072
3::1::25::15::55117
```

I know that I can solve this using: lambda function, split() command and int() command

Please your help with the code

Rodrigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do the following

```
rdd.map(lambda x: "::".join(['0' if(y == 'F') else '1' if(y == 'M') else y for y in x.split("::")]))
```

This will replace every element is the rows if `F` or `M` is found by `0` and `1`

So if you are looking for replacing only the second element then you can do the following

```
rdd.map(lambda x: x.split('::')).map(lambda x: "::".join([x[0]] + ['0' if(x[1] == 'F') else '1'] +x[2:]))
```

I hope the answer is helpful